# How to recall the window with the original creation settings of an object

Tags: modeling

After I place, for example a new mesh, and do any actions after that it is impossible to recall again the settings in the picture.

[image: n]

I know there is a way but I was not able to find an answer to that. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Simply put - there is no way. Blender doesn't have construction history :).

Comment: it works just like that: once you "do any actions after the creation" you cannot bring back the original parameters.